# Using Libraries in Rails (4.1.x) Engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

So the core issue at heart here is the following message:

```
`<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant Xaaron::Core (NameError)
```

So I think some of the steps I have done will be redundant, but I am new to trying to add code to my library folder in a rails engine, in rails its rather easy. But here its not so much.

So here is what I have done:

in:

```
xaaron/
  lib/
    xaaron/
```

I have a directory called `core/` with a file called `loder.rb`.

Inside of core is a directory called `controllers` and in side there is a file called `user_controller` which looks like:

```
module Xaaron
  module Core
    module UserController
      def assign_to_member_group(user)
        memeber = Xaron::Group.find('member')
        user.add_group = memeber.group_name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To load this I have  a loader file:

```
module Xaaron
  module Core
    module Loader
      include Xaaron::Core::Controllers::UserController
    end
  end
end
```

Which I do not think is needed because in the `engine.rb` file I do: `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../xaaron/core/**", __FILE__)` which just goes up one directory to the `lib/` directory and loads xaaron/core/ and everything in it (or so I thought).

This `loader.rb` file is included in the `ApplicationController`

```
module Xaaron
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ...

    include Xaaron::Core::Loader
    ...
  end
end
```

So:

- Whats the proper way to load my "core" library
- Why am I getting the error above?

Comment: Clarify what you want to load and from where. I mean, does `Xaaron::Core::Loader` comes from engine and `ApplicationController` from `main_app`?

Comment: Sorry about that: `Xaaron::Core::Loader` is in `xaaron/lib/xaaron/core/loader.rb` - its apart of the engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is with `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../xaaron/core/**", __FILE__)`. It expands into smth like `Rails.root/lib/engine_name/xaaron/core/**` and your lib path should be `Rails.root/lib/xaaron/core`. So, in your case, lib path should be `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../xaaron/core", __FILE__)`

Moreover, beeing within your `ApplicationController`, it is enough to include `include Core::Loader`, because you're already within `Xaaron` namespace.

Before you'll start working with controllers, try just call your module `Xaaron::Core::Loader` within `rails console`.

Comment: Now I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Core` in the `rails console`. I added `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path("../../xaaron/core", __FILE__)` to the `engine.rb` But I don't think that helped

Comment: It didn't. Have you checked into what path `File.expand_path("../../xaaron/core", __FILE__)` expands (by simply `puts` or debugging it)? If so, is your module in that directory?